# ASP C# GridView Update SQL Database from Edited Value

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, sql-update

I'm struggling with this code. I have a gridview that has a visible column and non-visible column (`Visible="False"`). The non-visible column is a system value, so I'd rather not show the user.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Del. Qty">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("QUANTITY")%>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" Text='<%# Eval("QUANTITY")%>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="System ID" Visible="False">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("SYS_ID")%>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSys" Text='<%# Eval("SYS_ID")%>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

The C# code:

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var row = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var txtQuantity = (TextBox) row.FindControl("txtQuantity");
    var txtSys = (TextBox) row.FindControl("txtSys");

    var qty = Convert.ToDecimal(txtQuantity.Text);
    var sysId = txtSys.Text;

    UpdateProduct(qty, sysId);
}
```

While Debugging, I noticed the problem is `txtSys` constantly shows as `NULL`. How can I make the value of the `SYS_ID` not visible to the user, yet usable in the update statement?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Visible=false`, the column is not rendered into the gridview. So when you try using `row.FindControl`, it will return NULL, since the controls doesn't really exist.

Instead of using `Visible=false`, surrond the item with a DIV which has no visibility:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <div style="visibility:hidden;">
       <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSys" Text='<%# Eval("SYS_ID")%>' />
    </div>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That worked for the update to the database, but the column is still visible to the end user. Is there a way to hide the column from the user and still "get" the value for the update?

Comment: @dot3tech Just wrap the items you want to hide with a `<div style="visibility:hidden;">`